# iOS parse black strip on profile picture (PFImageView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfimageview

I am using Parse as a backend of my app, and it seems that the profile photo is not displaying properly, shown in the image:
[image: notice the john appleseed]

there is a black strip on john_appleseed's photo.

here is my code for saving the profile image:

```
NSData *profileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cell1.profileView.image);
PFFile *profileFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"profilePhoto" data:profileData];
[profileFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
     {
          if (!error)
         {
             if (succeeded)
             {
                 [user setObject:profileFile forKey:@"profilePhoto"];
                 [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
                  {
                      if (!error)
                      {

                      }
                      else
                      {

                      }
                  }];
             }
         }
     }];
```

here is how I retrieve the image:(inside PFQueryTableViewController)

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    //NSLog(@"called");
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *filter = [defaults objectForKey:@"topicFilter"];
    NSLog(@"queryfortable: %@", filter);
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
    [query includeKey:@"user"];
    [query whereKey:@"category" equalTo:filter];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    return query;
}

- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == self.objects.count)
    {
        return nil;//this is for the load more cell.
    }
    return [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
```

in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object`

```
PFUser *user = [object objectForKey:@"user"];
PFImageView *profileImgView = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
profileImgView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImgView.frame.size.height/2;
profileImgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
PFFile *file = user[@"profilePhoto"];
profileImgView.file = file;
[profileImgView loadInBackground];
```

any ideas? many thanks.

Comment: what does the picture look like from the backend? is it a case of compression quality loss or does it display properly in the backend? If so, it's probably just a case of threading, `loadInBackground` is called asynchronously and UI components need to happen on the main thread

Comment: @soulshined the image on backend is perfectly fine. loadInBackground indeed, is called asynchronously, but let's say the network is slow, the imageView will just be a white blank view instead of black, until it is loaded.

Comment: So you load it in the background and when it's successful that's when you set `someImageView.image` to the profile picture in the call back

Comment: FYI, there was a typo in my first comment. Should have stated, if _not_ a quality loss issue, it's potential a threading issue.

Comment: @soulshined I'll give it a go. Also, this doesn't happen every time, sometimes it just worked fine, and sometimes it didn't.

Comment: Are you using `PFTableViewCell`?

Comment: @soulshined no, just UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

You should be updating user interfaces on the main thread. Since your loading something in the background, you should notify the main thread that it needs to update an object. `loadInBackground` is downloading the file asynchronously.

Here is an example, that you can alter for your needs, just to illustrate, that updating UI components in the call back has it's benefits; this is based off of Parses own [AnyPic](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic):

```
NSString *requestURL = file.url; // Save copy of url locally (will not change in block)

[file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //dispatch on main thread
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error on fetching file");
    }
}];
```

Comment: i used to use `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`, but have a look at this article: [Loading Images Stored on Parse](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/)

Comment: yes @GellertLee , either way `PFFile` is data (see [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html)), if you update your question with the method how you get 'user' or where you're actually setting the `PFImageView` in, I can edit it to suit your needs. This is a "one-size-fits-all" answer

Comment: see my edited question. I set the PFImageView in xib of my custom cell.